# Any ideas why recording audio would so slow down my entire app?

Tags: java, android, audio

So I have an app where I read from the microphone and record it to a file (in patches).

Even thought I have OnRecordPositionUpdateListener and all recorded related items in a separate thread, I get an extreme slow down on the main thread, the UI thread.  So while recording, my clicking on buttons on the screen are seriously delayed.

Using the process of commenting out coding I've narrowed it down all to the part where I pull data from the buffer.

```
int samplesRead = recorder.read(audioBuffer, 0, mAudioBufferSampleSize);
```

It's not the writing the data to local memory, or anything else (I've got that commented out while I try and find the problem).

Does anyone have any experience here and what I can do to somehow lessen the drag?

Here is the thread where I start, and write recording, after the user hits the Start button.

```
  public View.OnClickListener startListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        int x = 0;

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStop.setEnabled(true);
            inRecordMode = CURRENT_REC;

            if(!bInit)
            {
                bInit = true;

                Thread tSanyo = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        final String sPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/tapes";

                        try
                        {
                            int sampleRate = 44100;
                            int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
                            int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
                            mAudioBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                                    channelConfig, audioFormat);
                            mAudioBufferSampleSize = mAudioBufferSize * 10;
                            mAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                    sampleRate,
                                    channelConfig,
                                    audioFormat,
                                    mAudioBufferSampleSize);

                        }
                        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mAudioRecord.setNotificationMarkerPosition(mAudioBufferSampleSize/2);
                        mAudioRecord.setPositionNotificationPeriod(mAudioBufferSampleSize/2);

                        OnRecordPositionUpdateListener mListener = new OnRecordPositionUpdateListener()
                        {

                            String sTemp;
                            @Override
                            public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder)
                            {
                             }

                            public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)
                            {

                                short[] audioBuffer = new short[mAudioBufferSampleSize];

                                /////app slows to a crawl as soon as the first
                                /////recorder.read is called
                                int samplesRead = recorder.read(audioBuffer, 0, mAudioBufferSampleSize);

                            }
                        };
                        mAudioRecord.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(mListener);
                        int audioRecordState = mAudioRecord.getState();
                        if (audioRecordState != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                        {
                            finish();
                        }
                        if(mAudioRecord == null)
                            return;
                        short[] audioBuffer = new short[mAudioBufferSampleSize];
                        mAudioRecord.startRecording();
                        int audioRecordingState = mAudioRecord.getRecordingState();
                        if(audioRecordingState != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING)
                        {
                            finish();
                        }

                    }
                });
                tSanyo.start();
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: @AwaisAhmad I have edited the OP to reflect the entire thread

Comment: Small update.  If I don't bother with the setPositionNotification callback and just use a loop, it doesn't slow my tablet down at all.

`                     while(true)
                        {
                            int samplesRead = mAudioRecord.read(audioBuffer, 0, mAudioBufferSampleSize);
                            x++;
                        }`
  

That seems a little off to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is running on a separate thread? Or a separate core for that matter, if you're running a low end old school device, you might be stalling the CPU with one core.

How often do you read the samples? If you're continuously reading them, in a while loop, consider giving the CPU some slack and see if it helps.

Often you don't need that low latency audio that you think, but sometimes the Android can be too slow for real time audio applications, but not knowing which your one is, I'll take some guesses.

Easiest way to find out what and why is stalling your CPU or the main thread for that matter, is to use profiler, which of more you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html).

The profiler will tell how long each method execution takes, however, if your CPU is already stalled, it might be pretty slow to response to your start and stop of the profiler, however that can also be toggled programmatically.